Azure BlobClient not returning a seekable stream
I am serving a file from an endpoint like this:
[HttpGet("Files/{id}")]
[HttpHead("Files/{id}")]
public IActionResult GetFile(Guid id)
{
    var blob = Container.GetBlobClient(id.ToString().ToLower()); // Container is a BlobContainerClient
    var download = blob.Download();

    return File(download.Value.Content, "mime-type", "file name", enableRangeProcessing: true);
}

download.Value.Content is a non-seekable stream and this results in Azure serving a response without the content-length or accept-ranges headers. Which means that for large downloads the browser doesn't know how big the file ultimately will be and don't give a nice progress percent.
I was hoping to change my code to like this:
[HttpGet("Files/{id}")]
[HttpHead("Files/{id}")]
public IActionResult GetFile(Guid id)
{
    var blob = Container.GetBlobClient(id.ToString().ToLower());
    var stream = blob.OpenRead(new BlobOpenReadOptions(allowModifications: false)); ;

    return File(stream, "mime-type", "file name", enableRangeProcessing: true);
}

This does result in a seekable stream being served and all the right headers are generated.
But can't really find much info on the difference between these and especially on why .Download() isn't seekable. I tried blob.DownloadStreaming and blob.DownloadTo. Those work locally but throw exceptions in Azure.

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I'm using Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.14.1.0
Does my change have any appreciable downsides?


But can't really find much info on the difference between these and especially on why .Download() isn't seekable.

So from the source code, Download is giving you a RetriableStream which isn't seekable.
Additionally, Response<BlobDownloadInfo> looks like it'll load everything into memory, which for large files probably isn't desirable.

Does my change have any appreciable downsides?

It would seem like blob.OpenRead is an OK choice, I think better than Download. The reason the stream is seekable is that internally it's returning a LazyLoadingReadOnlyStream.
Doc's state the method Opens a stream for reading from the blob. The stream will only download the blob as the stream is read from. so you're streaming it from blob storage to the client which I believe should reduce memory pressure in your asp.net app.

Range queries could probably be used to simulate a seeking operation. OpenReadAsync takes options that let you specify the offset. DownloadContentAsync allows for BlobDownloadOptions where you can set the Range property.

Yes indeed - the range option is certainly helpful for offsets. But if I'm reading the source code correctly, I believe the "non-seekable" stream for Download is unavoidable due to it using the RetriableStream.

@PatrickHuber I found that making an HTTP request with a header value of Range: bytes=10-20 was not possible with Download. Because the stream is not seekable the requested range is ignored and the whole stream is returned. I think you could manually read the headers then pass that range into Download but that seems like  a lot of extra work for what OpenRead appears to do on its own.
